# How to put text over node in scenekit?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

Really simple question which for some reason I cannot find anywhere. How can I write 2D text on a 3D face of a `SCNNode`?
For example, on something like this:

```
let geo = SCNBox(width: 20, height: 20, length: 20, chamferRadius: 0.0);
//geo.writeFace(postion, text)
let box = SCNNode(geometry: geo);
```

Of course the comment is made up. Anything like it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to create a texture of the desired font and text, then apply that as a part of the material on the object. Though I've not seen anything like UVW mapping in Scene Kit to let you control the placement. It must be there. If you're only working with SCN geometry you might be OK, because SCNBox at least permits per side specification for material/texture.

You can dynamically create 2D type textures with either UIKit text drawing to a context, or rasterisation of Sprite Kit text with use of textureToNode:
 https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview/1520114-texturefromnode?language=objc

Comment: this seems rather inefficient...i guess thats the only option? weird.

Comment: SceneKit doesn't have decals or any other interesting ways of dynamically creating textures, either. I'm sure you'll be repeating "this seems rather inefficient..." internally more than a few times whilst battling with SpriteKit/SceneKit integration. And then there's GameplayKit ;)

Comment: how depressing! any other libraries you recommend that work similarly (scene, node, etc wise) but has this functionality?

Comment: I highly recommend Unreal Engine. It uses an Actor model, and its own form of composition and inheritance that's easy to understand and exploit. But it's a behemoth compared to SceneKit. cocos2D-X is a nightmare of flux, fragmentation and foibles. CryEngine is HUGE. Unity is a pig/dog/donkey hybrid. So... nope. Not really. If you can deal with the size issues (and performance on lesser iOS devices), Unreal Engine is the best choice. Enormous power, limitless potential.

Comment: SceneKit is a sign of intent, I think. Kind of like an early alpha of something going somewhere, but it's all going to depend on whether or not Apple gives the team enough money, resources and time to make it easy and enjoyable to use. Right now it's so unfinished, untested, unproven and unenjoyable that it's only real benefit is the radically fast build time. Make a Mac project and it almost launches instantly. This, for my iterative style of exploring design ideas makes it worthwhile to me. Not sure if I'll ever get beyond this basic sort of iterative exploration with it & making something.

Comment: thanks for all the further description (up vote). Going to take a look, sounds interesting!

Comment: I wish there was an easier/better answer to give you. Engine choice is a nightmare.

Comment: One other caveat with SceneKit, there's almost no userbase, therefore no community, and Apple's not provided ANYTHING on approaches to using it. Things like Phaser (http://phaser.io/examples) have over 500 little demos showcasing how and why to do things the suggested ways. One guy does most of it. That Apple doesn't do this kind of thing for SpriteKit and SceneKit is annoying and ominous.

Comment: I agree. its annoying! I might be being stupid - but cannot find any swift ios examples of  Unreal Engine...could you point me in the right direction? also, one thing i do like scenekit is its design (nodes, a scene, etc).  Does UE work similar to this (code wise)? For example, Three.js is extremely similar to scenekit in the way you add nodes to a scene, render, choose position, rotation, etc. If UE is far of this, ideally i dont want to change underlying logic of my code, so what other things are out there that are similar (but better in ways we've discussed)? again, huge thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124110/discussion-between-confused-and-harry-lakins).

Comment: I found something else interesting. You can find the texture coordinates and position of it on any face that has texture coordinates. This would require (probably) creating the UVW coordinates in a 3D app, on your model, then exporting it with that, and importing it and retaining it. Which would all be lots of trial and error messing around. But might help you with labelling geometry surfaces: https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnhittestresult/1522771-texturecoordinates

Comment: Yep. finally got it aligned nicely. Was A LOT of trial and error! cheers

Comment: @harrylakins could you post a solution to your question if you have it figured out? Trying to figure this out as well.

Comment: Hi there- I did end up using the SCNText, made it flat, and positioned it manually against the face - results are better than I thought!

Comment: @DanBeaulieu see harry's response. He forgot to tag you, so you might have missed his answer. i got notified cause your comments are under my answer.